# Indirect Recursion in C++ Using const Keyword

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion, constants, determinants

In my program I am trying to calculate the determinant of a matrix (2D array) using indirect recursion to perform cofactor expansion (i.e. two functions recursively call each other each). However, the compiler complains that it cannot convert the double** to const double**, even though it should be legal to pass a const parameter to another const parameter in recursion, right? What am I doing wrong?

Compliation

```
make clean && make
rm -f *.o determinant
clang++-3.5 -g -Wall -std=c++11 -c determinant.cpp -o determinant.o
determinant.cpp:26:13: error: no matching function for call to 'determinant'
    cout << determinant(matrix, MATRIX_SIZE) << endl;
            ^~~~~~~~~~~
./determinant.h:7:8: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion
      from 'double **' to 'const double **' for 1st argument
double determinant(const double** matrix, int n);
       ^
determinant.cpp:71:15: warning: implicit conversion of NULL constant to 'int'
      [-Wnull-conversion]
        int colRef = NULL;
            ~~~~~~   ^~~~
                     0
determinant.cpp:85:48: error: no matching function for call to 'determinant'
        double cofactor = pow(-1, i) * matrix[i][0] * determinant(submatrix, n-1);
                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~
determinant.cpp:42:8: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion
      from 'double **' to 'const double **' for 1st argument
double determinant(const double** matrix, int n)
       ^
1 warning and 2 errors generated.
make: *** [determinant.o] Error 1
```

Source File

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>
#include "determinant.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Matrix initialization
    const int MATRIX_SIZE = 5;
    double** matrix = new double*[MATRIX_SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < MATRIX_SIZE; i++)
    {
        matrix[i] = new double[MATRIX_SIZE];
    }

    matrix[0][0] = 4; matrix[0][1] = 0; matrix[0][2] = -7; matrix[0][3] = 3; matrix[0][4] = -5;
    matrix[1][0] = 0; matrix[1][1] = 0; matrix[1][2] = 2; matrix[1][3] = 0; matrix[1][4] = 0;
    matrix[2][0] = 7; matrix[2][1] = 3; matrix[2][2] = -6; matrix[2][3] = 4; matrix[2][4] = -8;
    matrix[3][0] = 5; matrix[3][1] = 0; matrix[3][2] = 5; matrix[3][3] = 2; matrix[3][4] = -3;
    matrix[4][0] = 0; matrix[4][1] = 0; matrix[4][2] = 9; matrix[4][3] = -1; matrix[4][4] = 2;

    // Determinant should be 6.

    cout << determinant(matrix, MATRIX_SIZE) << endl;

    // Recycles memory used by matrix.
    for (int i = 0; i < MATRIX_SIZE; i++)
    {
        delete[] matrix[i];
    }

    delete[] matrix;

    return 0;
}

// Predefine: matrix is a two dimensional array representing a square n x n matrix.
// n is the dimension of the matrix.
// Returns the determinant of the given matrix.
double determinant(const double** matrix, int n)
{
    switch (n)
    {
    // If the matrix is a 1x1 matrix, the determinant is equal to itself.
    case 1:
        return matrix[0][0];

    default:
        return cofactorExpansion(matrix, n);
    }
}

// Predefine: matrix is a two dimensional array representing a square n x n matrix.
// n is the dimension of the matrix.
// i is the current iteration of monomial in the cofactor expansion (by default zero).
// Returns the determinant of a matrix where n > 2.
double cofactorExpansion(const double** matrix, int n, int i)
{
    // By definition of cofactor expansion, the determinant of A is equal to
    // (-1)^2 * a[1][1] * det(A[1][1]) + ... +(-1)^(i+1) * a[1][i] * det(A[1][j]) + ... + (-1)^(n+1) * a[1][n] * det(A[1][n]) (not assuming zero based indexing);
    // where a[i][j] is the value at row i and column j, and A[i][j] is the
    // matrix not including the ith row, and jth column. A cofactor is
    // defined to be one monomial of the cofactor expansion.

    if (i < n)
    {
        // Creates an (n-1)x(n-1) square matrix removing the first row and ith column.
        double** submatrix = new double*[n-1];
        int colRef = NULL;

        for (int subCol = 0; subCol < n-1; subCol++)
        {
            colRef = ((subCol < i) ? subCol : subCol + 1);
            submatrix[subCol] = new double[n-1];

            for (int subRow = 0; subRow < n-1; subRow++)
            {
                submatrix[subCol][subRow] = matrix[colRef][subRow+1];
            }
        }

        // Performs calculation of a cofactor for the column i.
        double cofactor = pow(-1, i) * matrix[i][0] * determinant(submatrix, n-1);

        // Recycles the memory of the submatrix.
        for (int subCol = 0; subCol < n-1; subCol++)
        {
            delete[] submatrix[subCol];
        }

        delete[] submatrix;

        return cofactor + cofactorExpansion(matrix, n, i+1);
    }

    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The header file only contains the declaration of the two functions and are nothing special.

Comment: main has no idea there exists function called determinant. Forward declare it, or move the definition before main(C++ is compiled top to down). Additionally, NULL should never be used to initialize int, it is meant to be used with pointers(in C, it is even of type (void*)0, in C++ 0 unfortunately), and is even outdated(C++11 added nullptr)

Comment: @Creris See the inclusion of `determinant.h` :)